# Mathnet errors when trying to solve a multiple regression equation

Tags: c#, math, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I have the following code and I'm trying with 2 different methods to solve a multiple regression equation. The arrays are too long to list but the count on each one matches at 5704 lines. I'm getting the following errors when I try to run the code

// getting An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in MathNet.Numerics.dll

Additional information: Matrix must be positive definite.

```
double[] p = Fit.MultiDim(
                new[] { shortRatingList.ToArray(), mediumRatingList.ToArray(), longRatingList.ToArray() },
                weekReturnList.ToArray(),
                intercept: true);
```

// getting An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in MathNet.Numerics.dll

Additional information: Matrix dimensions must agree: 3x5705.

```
                double[] q = MultipleRegression.QR(
                new[] { shortRatingList.ToArray(), mediumRatingList.ToArray(), longRatingList.ToArray() },
                weekReturnList.ToArray(),
                intercept: true);
```

Comment: @MitchWheat I'm posting on this website because I don't know how to fix these exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet in the question computes a regression with 3 sample points (each one of them with 5704 values), so it expects `weekReturnList` to be of length 3.

However, if `weekReturnList` has length 5704 as well and your data actually represents 5704 data points with 3 values each (short, medium, long) then you need to transpose the input.

I assume that data organized by columns instead of data points is quite common in practice, so we should consider to add a shortcut function for this use case in the `Fit` class as well.

In the meantime you could use the following, which transposes the input by creating the design matrix from column arrays instead of row arrays:

```
MultipleRegression.NormalEquations(
    Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfColumnArrays(shortRatingList, mediumRatingList, longRatingList),
    Vector<double>.Build.Dense(weekReturnList));
```

Comment: This will generate the coefficient for each sample point? I think I'm using that term correctly

Comment: This will find the 3 coefficients which minimize the error for the 5704 data samples such that p1*short + p2*medium + p3*long ~= weekReturn. Does that make any sense? You did not actually specify the model you want a regression for ;)

Comment: Just noticed that you asked for an intercept term (and thus 4 coefficients). The simplest way to do this with that function is to insert an all-one vector first (e.g. `Generate.Repeat(5704, 1.0)`), before the other 3.

Comment: I'm using multiple regression for a school project and to be honest I barely know what it is and how to do it. I'm much better with linear regression. Actually I only had the intercept term in there because of the example I saw. What my project is supposed to do is come up with 3 different ways to score a stock based on different data and then try to come up with an expected return. I hope I'm coming across clear

Comment: Seems we're on the right way then, with `expectedWeekReturn = p1*shortRating + p2*mediumRating + p3*longRating` where the p-parameters are the 3 results returned by the NormalEquations function.

Comment: I know I already marked it as answered but is there a way to see the error or calculate the error amount from the multiple regression?

Comment: GoodnessOfFit.RSquared may help to get an indication of the error, e.g. `GoodnessOfFit.RSquared(
    Enumerable.Range(0,weekReturnList.Length).Select(i => f(shortRatingList[i], mediumRatingList[i], longRatingList[i])),
    weekReturnList);` with `Func<double,double,double,double> f = (rs,rm,rl) => p[0]*rs + p[1]*rm + p[2]*rl`. See also See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940868/linear-fit-with-math-net-error-in-data-and-error-in-fit-parameters